# Shaping a Pandas DataFrame (multiple columns into 2)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simular dataframe to below and require it to be shaped as per expected output.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'col1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'col2': [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11],
                   'col3': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
                  })

    col1  col2  col3
0    A     1     2
1    A     3     4
2    A     5     6
3    B     7     8
4    B     9    10
5    B    11    12
```

**Expected Output**

```
df_expected = pd.DataFrame({
                            'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                            'B': [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
                           })

   A   B
0  1   7
1  2   8
2  3   9
3  4  10
4  5  11
5  6  12
```

So far I have tried `pack`, `unpack` & `pivot` without getting the desired result

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use `Numpy` to reshape the data then package back up into a dataframe.

```
cols = (df['col2'],df['col3'])
data = np.stack(cols,axis=1).reshape(len(cols),len(df))
dft = pd.DataFrame(data, index=df['col1'].unique()).T

print(dft)
```

**Result**

```
   A   B
0  1   7
1  2   8
2  3   9
3  4  10
4  5  11
5  6  12
```

Comment: Your output seems to be missing the last row. `6 12`

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('col1').agg(list).T.sum().to_dict())
```